# how to get only numbers inside tags leaving texts

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

here is my p iam intrested in only phone numbers not texts

```html
<p class="phone-list">
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>8046033006<script type="text/javascript"> whicVer('vers1');</script></span>
</p>
<p class="phone-list">
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>12345566<script type="text/javascript"> whicVer('vers2');</script></span>
</p>
```

I wanted to get only phone number, ie. `8046033006` & `12345566` through this code I am getting

```
$('.phone-list span:nth-child(2)').each(function()
  console.log($(this).text());
);
```

the output looks like something....

- `8046033006 whicVer('vers1')`
- `12345566 whicVer('vers2')`

I have observed why script tag is not printing? Please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex. Or just use a little span just around the number.

```
var removedText = initialText.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

For your case it would be:

```
$('.phone-list span:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
  var num = $(this).text().replace(/\D/g, '')
  console.log(num);
);
```

Here is a little **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eu0oosqr/)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the HTML structure is the same for all `.phone-list` elements, you can retrieve the first textNode from the second child `span` and get it's `nodeValue`. Try this:

```js
$('.phone-list span:nth-child(2)').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).contents()[0].nodeValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="phone-list">
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>8046033006<script type="text/javascript">//whicVer('vers1');</script></span>
</p>
<p class="phone-list">
    <span>hello</span>
    <span>12345566<script type="text/javascript">//whicVer('vers2');</script></span>
</p>
```

Note that I only commented out the `whicVer()` function calls as they were giving errors in the snippet.

Comment: sir, whicVer() will be present in every <span>. i need to remove

Comment: That's fine - you can leave it in your actual code. Like I said above, I only removed it for the sake of the example

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the text from the DOM , you can use regex like this

```
// text from which number will be seperated
var number = "8046033006hriughidhgiudhgiudthgiuhdiutg"
document.write('<pre>'+number.match(/\d+/)[0]+'</pre>')
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/s0ogc7na/)